# progress view stop button listener

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I develop an eclipse plugin and I added an eclipse progress view to it. There is an stop button on the progress view and I want to create some kind of listener to handle the events of the chancel button, but I don't know how I can do it. I know the monitor has an isChancel() method, but I have to create come kind of listener to listen when user clicks the stop button, while the plugin works. Please give me some advice. Thanks

Example:

[link text](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.r2a.doc/topics/rprogressview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it. Progress View/IProgressService doesn't provide any such APIs. One way is, if you know which job, the progress belongs to, then you can call job.cancel().